# Can't get some characters while generating a PDF using iText

Tags: html, pdf, itext, tidy

I use iText to convert HTML to PDF.  HTML could has any language, so for testing I have the following HTML :

```html
<html>
<head/>

<body>
  </div>
  <div dir="ltr">
    <br />
    <div style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-family:arial,sans-serif;font-size:12.8px;font-style:normal;font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-weight:400;letter-spacing:normal;text-align:start;text-indent:0px;text-transform:none;white-space:normal;word-spacing:0px;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);text-decoration-style:initial;text-decoration-color:initial">
      <div>
        ů&nbsp; Ů
      </div>
      <div>
        <br />
      </div>
      <div>
        š č ť ý á í é ú Ě Ň
      </div>
      <div>
        <br />
      </div>
      <div>
        δ ζ ψ φ ξ λ μ π ρ ε ς α σ&nbsp;
      </div>
      <div>
        <br />
      </div>
      <div>
        ΔΣΨΦΓΩΞΛΠΘ
      </div>
      <br />ı ğ ç ö ü ş İ Ğ Ç Ö Ü Ş
      <br />
      <br />Č Ć Š Ž Đ
      <br />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I use "Tidy" to clean and process this HTML :

```
public String convertToXHTML1(String htmlText) throws FileNotFoundException {
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlText.getBytes());
    OutputStream os = new OutputStream() {
        private StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            this.string.append((char) b);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return this.string.toString();
        }
    };
    Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
    tidy.setXHTML(true);

    tidy.setQuiet(false);
    tidy.setShowWarnings(true);
    tidy.setShowErrors(1);
    tidy.setMakeClean(true);
    tidy.setForceOutput(true);
    tidy.setNumEntities(false);
    tidy.setInputEncoding("utf8");
    tidy.setOutputEncoding("raw");
    //tidy.setRawOut(true);

    org.w3c.dom.Document doc = tidy.parseDOM(is, os);//in,out);
    String xhtmlText = os.toString();
    return xhtmlText;
}
```

and the resualt is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="generator"
content="HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 2009-12-01), see jtidy.sourceforge.net" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div dir="ltr"><br />
 
<div
style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-family:arial,sans-serif;font-size:12.8px;font-style:normal;font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-weight:400;letter-spacing:normal;text-align:start;text-indent:0px;text-transform:none;white-space:normal;word-spacing:0px;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);text-decoration-style:initial;text-decoration-color:initial">
<div>&#367;&nbsp; &#366;</div>
<div><br />
</div>
<div>&scaron; &#269; &#357; &yacute; &aacute; &iacute; &eacute;
&uacute; &#282; &#327;</div>
<div><br />
</div>
<div>&delta; &zeta; &psi; &phi; &xi; &lambda; &mu; &pi; &rho;
&epsilon; &sigmaf; &alpha; &sigma;&nbsp;</div>
<div><br />
</div>
<div>
&Delta;&Sigma;&Psi;&Phi;&Gamma;&Omega;&Xi;&Lambda;&Pi;&Theta;</div>
</div>
<br />
&#305; &#287; &ccedil; &ouml; &uuml; &#351; &#304; &#286; &Ccedil;
&Ouml; &Uuml; &#350;<br />
<br />
&#268; &#262; &Scaron; &#381; &#272;<br />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

then I use iText to have ByteArrayOutputStream of PDF to save it as pdf file on google drive.

```
public static ByteArrayOutputStream createPdfFromHtml(String htmlBody) throws DocumentException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {

        Document document = new Document();//(PageSize.A4);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
        document.open();
        log.info("convert the email message body (given as XHTML) to PDF stream");

        // CSS
        CSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(true);

        // HTML
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new MySpecialImageProviderAwareHtmlPipelineContext();

        htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
        htmlContext.setImageProvider(new MyImageProvider());

        // Pipelines
        PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
        HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
        CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

        // XML Worker
        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
        XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);

        p.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlBody.getBytes("UTF-8")), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        document.close();

    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  outputStream;
}
```

The resault should be look like :

ů  Ů

š č ť ý á í é ú Ě Ň

δ ζ ψ φ ξ λ μ π ρ ε ς α σ

ΔΣΨΦΓΩΞΛΠΘ

ı ğ ç ö ü ş İ Ğ Ç Ö Ü Ş

Č Ć Š Ž Đ

but I have the following result:

ů  Ů

š č ť ý á í é ú Ě Ň

δ ζ ψ φ ξ λ μ π ρ ε ς α σ

ΔΣΨΦΓΩΞΛΠΘ

ç ö ü    Ç Ö Ü

Š Ž

Just the Turkish characters don't correctly converted!
I don't know if the should I add new font to iText or the problem is Tidy has not correctly convert these characters?

Comment: It works better if you don't use the older `XMLWorker`, but use the current iText 7.1.1 + pdfHTML 2.0.1 instead. It also works better if you use a font that contains the characters.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse How can I use or add fonts to my ByteArrayOutputStream? All fonts examples in iText are used in adding new Paragraph case, which does not fit my case.